# MySQL Crosstab Query for Profile Table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, crosstab, entity-attribute-value

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `profiles`

```
INSERT INTO `profiles` (`id`, `user`, `field`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'jd', 'Name', 'John Doe'),
(2, 'jd', 'Phone', '0300000000'),
(3, 'rm', 'Name', 'Roger Moore'),
(4, 'rm', 'Phone', '03111111111');
```

I want to view the data as below.

```
Name | Phone
Johns Doe | 0300000000
Roger Moore | 03111111111
```

Comment: I think Roger Moore's number is 007

Comment: @Strawberry   ..absolutely

Comment: This is not really a "pivot" or "crosstab"; it is more like "EAV".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join  on profiles table

and use inner join if all the user  match for both the field

```
select a.value Name, b.value  Phone
from profiles a
inner join profiles b on a.user = b.user and b.field='Phone' 
where a.field='Name'
```

otherwise  you should use left join

```
select a.value Name, b.value  Phone
from profiles a
left join profiles b on a.user = b.user and b.field='Phone' AND  a.field='Name'
```

Comment: That would normally be an outer join